# Finding better logic for addition and removal of Nodes in a Linked List

Tags: java, performance, linked-list

Consider the following piece of code I wrote (a templated Linked List):

```java
package com.data_structures;

public class LinkedList<NodeDataType> {

    public LinkedList() {
        super();
    }

    class LinkedListNode<DataType> {
        private DataType data;
        LinkedListNode<DataType> nextNode;
    
        public LinkedListNode(DataType data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.nextNode = null;
        }
    
        public DataType getData() {
            return data;
        }
    
        public void setData(DataType data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(data).toString();
        }
    
    }

    private LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> rootNode = null;

    private int nodeCount = 0;

    private void addTail(LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> node) {
        LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp = rootNode;
        while (temp.nextNode != null) {
            temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
        temp.nextNode = node;
    }

    private void changeRoot(LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> node) {
        node.nextNode = this.rootNode;
        this.rootNode = node;
    }

    private void addNodeAt(LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> node, int position) {
        LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp = this.rootNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < position - 1; i++) {
            temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
        node.nextNode = temp.nextNode;
        temp.nextNode = node;
    }

    public LinkedList(NodeDataType data) {
        this.rootNode = new LinkedListNode<>(data);
        this.nodeCount++;
    }

    public int getNodeCount() {
        return nodeCount;
    }

    public void addNode(NodeDataType data, int position) {
        LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> node = new LinkedListNode<>(data);
        if (position <= 1 || this.rootNode == null) {
            changeRoot(node);
        }
        else if (position >= this.nodeCount) {
            addTail(node);
        }
        else {
            addNodeAt(node, position);
        }
        this.nodeCount++;
    }

    private void eraseRoot() {
        this.rootNode = this.rootNode.nextNode;
    }

    private void eraseTail() {
        LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp = this.rootNode;
        LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp2 = temp;
        while (temp.nextNode != null) {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
        temp2.nextNode = null;
    }
    
    private void eraseNodeAt(int position) {
        LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp = this.rootNode;
        LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> temp2 = temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < position - 1; i++) {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
        temp2.nextNode = temp.nextNode;
    }

    public void deleteNode(int position) {
        if (position <= 1) {
            eraseRoot();
        }
        else if (position >= this.nodeCount) {
            eraseTail();
        }
        else {
            eraseNodeAt(position);
        }
        this.nodeCount--;
    }

    public NodeDataType getNode(int position) {
        if (position <= 1) {
            return this.rootNode.data;
        }
        else {
            LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> node = this.rootNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < position - 1 && node.nextNode != null; i++) {
                node = node.nextNode;
            }
            return node.data;
        }
    }


}
```

If we take a careful look at `addNode` and `deleteNode` functions, we see that I essentially had to write separate logic for "ends" and "in-betweeners". I don't usually code in Java, and am not very good at Java. Is there a better logic for these 2 functions?

Comment: With the language you are most comfortable with, do you know the way to avoid the _separate logic_?

Comment: @vnp *do you know the way to avoid the separate logic?* frankly, that's part of the question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Template Type Parameter

You've used `NodeDataType` for your `LinkedList` template type parameter, and `DataType` for your `LinkedListNode` template type parameter.  Why are these different?

Considering your code is littered with `LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType>` types, it seems you want the same type used for both classes.

But if you want the same type, why are you specifying it twice?

## Nested Types

What is the type name for the list's internal nodes?  It is not `LinkedListNode`; it is `LinkedList::LinkedListNode`.  Somewhat verbose? A little too redundant?  Perhaps `Node` is sufficient.

## Organization

Put like thing together.  Inside `LinkedList`, you have a constructor, then a type definition, then data members, then methods, then another constructor, then more methods.

Better would be a type definition, data members, constructors, and methods.

## Access restriction

Why is `data` private, but `nextNode` isn't?

Does anything external to `LinkedList` need access to the internal node structure at all?  Internal nodes are never returned by a `public` method, so the entire class could be `private`.

## super

Why is does the `LinkedList()` constructor calling `super()` when there is no parent class defined?

Why doesn't the `LinkedList(NodeDataType data)` constructor call `super()`?

## First Rework

Applying the above points, you're code can look more like:

```java
class LinkedList<DataType> {

   private class Node {           // No need for an additional template parameter type!
      private DataType data;
      Node next;

      /* constructors & methods */
   }
   
   private Node rootNode = null;
   private int nodeCount = 0;
   
   public LinkedList() {
   }
   
   public LinkedList(DataType data) {
       addNode(data, 1);
   }
   
   /* methods */
}
```

Notice the second constructor isn't creating a node, setting it to root, and incrementing the node count; it is just using a routine which will already do this for you.

## Redundant code

You've written the following code a few times:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < position - 1; i++) {
            temp = temp.nextNode;
        }
```

It is in `addNodeAt`, `getNode`.  Very similar code is in `eraseNodeAt`.  Even `addTail`, and `eraseTail`, are close to this code, if you consider the tail is at position `nodeCount`.

Let's write the code once:

```
    private Node findNode(int position) {
        if (position < 1 || position > nodeCount)
            raise IndexOutOfBoundsException("Position is not within linked list");

        Node node = rootNode;
        for(int i = 1; i < position; i++) {
            node = node.nextNode;
        }

        return node;
    }
```

Note: I've made indexes outside the range `1 <= position <= nodeCount` an error, as opposed to silently treating those as the head or tail nodes.

Now we can easily use this helper function in other functions:

```
    public DataType getNode(int position) {
        Node node = findNode(position);
        return node.getData();
    }
```

Adding and removing nodes can use this too.  But we need to be a little careful.  To add or remove a node at `position`, we need to access the node at `position - 1` and manipulate that node's `nextNode`.  To add/remove the node at the root, there is no node before it, so that will remain a special case.  Eg)

```
    public void addNode(DataType data, int position) {
        Node new_node = new Node(data);
        if (position == 1) {
            new_node.nextNode = rootNode;
            rootNode = new_node;
        } else {
            Node prev_node = findNode(position - 1);
            new_node.nextNode = prev_node.nextNode;
            prev_node.nextNode = new_node;
        }
        nodeCount++;
    }
```

Note that adding at the tail is not a special case, since `prev.nextNode` will contain `null` before the addition, and that `null` value is simply copied to the new node's `nextNode`.

Similar code for `deleteNode` left to student.

Comment: *You've used NodeDataType for your LinkedList template type parameter, and DataType for your LinkedListNode template type parameter. Why are these different?* When I used DataType as the type parameter for both the outer class and the inner class, Visual Studio Code gave me a "mask" warning. That is why I'd to do it like that, but I think the way you've suggested is better because it'll reduce the redundancy in the code, for the use case where NodeDataType and DataType have different values is practically and logically impossible :)

Comment: *Considering your code is littered with LinkedList<NodeDataType>.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType> types, it seems you want the same type used for both classes.* Um... I didn't quite understand this. Please you please explain this part? Do you mean, I can do *LinkedList.LinkedListNode<NodeDataType>* and it will still logically be the same?

Comment: *I've made indexes outside the range 1 <= position <= nodeCount an error, as opposed to silently treating those as the head or tail nodes* That is what I would have done normally, but that was a part of the assignment. That is why I had to do it like that :)

Comment: *Why is does the LinkedList() constructor calling super() when there is no parent class defined?* Isn't the parent class `Object` by default?